# Grid Reduce the gap between Columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using Grid but the gaps between columns are bigger than expected.

I've used the code below in my style sheet but doesn't appear to work:

```
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    justify-items: center;

}
```

```
<div class="container">

<div class="products_all">

{% for products in products %}

{% if products.name %}


    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
       <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ products.name }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ products.description }}</p>
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere Nice</a>
  </div> <!-- card -->
</div> <!-- card body -->
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div> <!--   </div> col end div --->
</div> <!--- products_all ---->
```

Comment: https://d.pr/i/YZ7Ala

Comment: you should share your code... so that we can replicate the issue and offer advice for a fix

Comment: added the html code above :)